# Find start and end of a context in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, abstract-syntax-tree, python-3.7

I am trying to find the line number of the start and the end of a context. In Python **2.7** I am able to successfully do so as follows:

```
1 from contextlib import contextmanager
2 import sys
3
4 @contextmanager
5 def print_start_end_ctx():
6     frame = sys._getframe(2)
7     start_line = frame.f_lineno
8     yield
9     end_line = frame.f_lineno
10    print("start_line={}\nend_line={}".format(start_line, end_line))
11 
12 with print_start_end_ctx():
13     100
14     (200,
15      300)
```

Output in **Python 2.7**:

```
start_line=12
end_line=15
```

However, extracting line numbers from `frame` object fails in **Python 3.7**:

```
start_line=12
end_line=14
```

Comment: It's not that it fails, you just get a different result. It may well be that in 3.7 it considers the beginning of a final run-on line to be the last line proper. This makes sense, for example if you wanted to re-parse the last 'line' in the frame. In some ways the 2.7 behaviour is more surprising.